# get data from database and display it in gridview (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I have a database (SQL server) and I added it into my webpage project but the problem is I cannot display the data in a `gridview`.

Here is my code:

```
string query;
SqlCommand SqlCommand;
SqlDataReader reader;
int sindex=DropDownList1.SelectedIndex+1;
int hindex =DropDownList3.SelectedIndex+1;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
//Open the connection to db
conn.Open();                
query = string.Format("select * from table where clumn='"+s+"' ", s);
SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);              
reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();               
GridView2.DataSource = reader;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
query = string.Format("select * from table where clumn='"+s+"' ", s);
```

to this

```
query = string.Format("select * from table where clumn='{0}' ", s);
```

Comment: Actually, just use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlParameters instead of manipulating a string as you are doing now.
Also, use [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to dispose objects correctly.
Don't use `select *` because it will affect performance, only select the columns needed.
Here an example of your code, modified:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "select column, column2 from table where column=@column";

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("column", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    command.Parameters["column"].Value = yourColumnValue;

    conn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = sco.ExecuteReader())
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = sdr;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better use [SqlDatadapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 ...
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter( new SqlCommand(query, conn)))
                  {
                      GridView2.DataSource =a.Fill(dt).AsDataView();
                  }
```